# Layout different on android 2.3

Tags: android, android-layout

My buttons on 2.3 are not showing like the suppose to.

Anyone could help me?

This is how they are shown on 2.3:

[image]

And this is on 4.4 how it should be:

[image]

This is my layout on V9:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<TableLayout
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
android:id="@+id/numkeyBoard"
>

<TableRow
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button
        style="@style/test.Button.Num"
        android:id="@+id/button_1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:text="1"
        android:tag="1" />

    <Button
        style="@style/test.Button.Num"
        android:id="@+id/button_2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:text="2"
        android:tag="2" />

    <Button
        style="@style/test.Button.Num"
        android:text="3"
        android:id="@+id/button_3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:tag="3" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button
        style="@style/test.Button.Num"
        android:text="4"
        android:id="@+id/button_4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"

        android:tag="4" />

    <Button
        style="@style/test.Button.Num"
        android:text="5"
        android:id="@+id/button_5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:tag="5" />

    <Button
        style="@style/test.Button.Num"
        android:text="6"
        android:id="@+id/button_6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:tag="6" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button
        style="@style/test.Button.Num"
        android:text="7"
        android:id="@+id/button_7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:tag="7" />

    <Button
        style="@style/test.Button.Num"
        android:text="8"
        android:id="@+id/button_8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:tag="8" />

    <Button
        style="@style/test.Button.Num"
        android:text="9"
        android:id="@+id/button_9"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"

        android:tag="9" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button
        style="@style/test.Button.Num"
        android:text="C"
        android:id="@+id/button_c"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:tag="C" />

    <Button
        style="@style/test.Button.Num"
        android:text="0"
        android:id="@+id/button_0"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"

        android:tag="0"
        />

    <Button
        style="@style/test.Button.Num"
        android:text="OK"
        android:id="@+id/button_ok"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:tag="ok" />
</TableRow>
```

EDIT:

When I add a number second number to 1 2 3 ... until 9 then the buttons are all the same. 
How can I fix this without adding a 2 digit?

Comment: A few things to try: `TableRow` elements don't need width and height. Your `Button`s should have `layout_width=0dp` and `layout_weight=1`. The `TableLayout` should probably have `layout_width=match_parent`. It would be helpful to post the `test.Button.Num` style because that may have an effect.

Comment: can you provide me the "@style/test.Button.Num"?

Comment: <style name="test.Button.Num" parent="test.Button.Green">
        <item name="android:layout_width">40dp</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">24sp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/test_button_text</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    </style>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `android:stretchColumns="*"` to the attributes defined under `TableLayout`

Comment: I've added that to every Tablerow but this doens't change anything? Do I need to add it to the button instead of the Tablerow?

Comment: Not the tablerows but to the tablelayout itself. AFAIK, it won't work when adding to the tablerows or any of the children.

Comment: Thanks that worked. Now they are big. Not the same as the original but it's oké.